# iPhone 4 does not present a UIDocumentInteractionController

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone-4

I have this strange problem that only occurs in iPhone 4 with iOS 7. When I try to present a `UIDocumentInteractionController` on to the screen, application is stuck on `presentPreviewAnimated` method. The same thing happens in a different place when I try to use `MPMoviePlayerViewController`, only this time it is stuck on `initWithContentURL`. No error is thrown. I know that it is not much info I provided, but I don't have a clue how these things can be related and thus I don't know what information would be helpful. In my project I am using the following structure of Views.

```
HomeViewController * homeViewController = [[HomeViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"HomeViewController" bundle:nil];
MenuTableViewController * menuViewController = [[MenuTableViewController alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStylePlain];
ECSlidingViewController * slidingViewController = [[ECSlidingViewController alloc] init];
slidingViewController.topViewController = homeViewController;
slidingViewController.underLeftViewController = menuViewController;
UINavigationController * navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:slidingViewController];
self.window.rootViewController = navigationController;
```

For example when I debug the code:

```
_docController = [UIDocumentInteractionController interactionControllerWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:filePath]];
_docController.delegate = self;
[_docController presentPreviewAnimated:YES];
NSLog(@"Document showed");
```

The @"Document showed" message is never logged.

Application works great on the iPad and iPhone 5.
In my project I am using CocoaPods.

Please ask any questions that can help with finding the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try below code, hope it will be helpful.
set UIDocumentInteractionControllerDelegate in .h file

```
 @interface NextViewController : UIViewController <UIDocumentInteractionControllerDelegate>
```

Create object of UIDocumentInteractionController and initialise it.

```
 - (IBAction)openDocument:(id)sender
 {
      NSString* path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"fileName" ofType:@"fileType"]; // File types - .pdf, .txt, .jpg, .png, or any other.
      if (path)
      {
          NSURL* url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
          UIDocumentInteractionController* docController = [UIDocumentInteractionController interactionControllerWithURL:url];
          docController.delegate = self;
          [docController presentPreviewAnimated:YES];
      }
 }
```

Implement its delegate method.

```
 #pragma mark - UIDocumentInteractionControllerDelegate

 - (UIViewController *)documentInteractionControllerViewControllerForPreview:(UIDocumentInteractionController *)controller
 {
   return self;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Turned out that iPhone 4 manages threads differently than other newer devices. I had an error in not directly related place resulting in an endless loop.

```
while (self.delegate && ![self.delegate dataLoaderOperationCanStop:self]) 
{
[[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] runMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode beforeDate:[NSDate distantFuture]];
}
```

All other devices showed those ViewControllers with no problem, only iPhone 4 was stuck. I hope that my problem will help someone with similar strange application behavior.